# Carrying a checkbox selection in a session

Tags: php, session, checkbox

How do I wrap the selections in a session that can be carried over multiple pages?

This is what I have:

```
session_start();


<form action="checkbox-form.php" method="post">
Select your options<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="A" />A<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="B" />B<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="C" />C<br />
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>


var_dump($_POST['options']);


foreach($_POST['options'] as &$option){
  mysql_real_escape_string($option);
}


$insert = "INSERT INTO submitted (statuses)       
VALUES ('". implode(",", $_POST['options']) ."')";      

$query = mysql_query($insert) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

So, how do I put `$_POST['options'];` in a session.  I tried doing

```
$_SESSION['options'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['options']);
```

When i do that i get "array" as the result.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing a array in session variable and complaining that its returning me a array!!!

Of course it will return an array...to access a particular key of the same use..

$_SESSION['options'][0]
$_SESSION['options'][1]
$_SESSION['options'][2]

which consecutively correspond to your A,B,C checkboxes on the form...

Comment: this is what i don't get.  what do you mean 0, 1, 2??

Comment: That means your all 3 check boxes values are present in the session..and if u want to check the value of your A checkbox do it as: $_SESSION['options'][0]

Comment: Dude no one would want to carry all 30 checkboxes in session...why would you need all 30's information across pages...Store only the checkboxes info which are required..

Answer (score 0):

simply do it

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['options'] = $_POST['options'];
```

and you can access checkbox value by

```
$_SESSION['options'][$i] where $i <count($_SESSION['options'])
```